# GetFeatureInfo on GeoServer - what parameters/variables are available

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo, template

I am customizing the HTML response from GetFeatureInfo on GeoServer. GeoServer uses [freemarker templates](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) (content.ftl) to build the HTML response.

The attributes are available as a list. Since the findings are related to grid cells with unique ids I can create a string of the relevant grid cells. This string can again be used to build a URL which is sent to an API connected to my database.

I plan on using iframe to present the API response. This way I can get richer content on my HTML response.

Building the API based on the above is possible. But it would be better if I could forward the original bounding box info to the GetFeatureInfo request.

Is the bounding box available from within the GetFeatureInfo freemarker template? If so, how do I request it and forward it to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On HTML response, checking "org.geoserver.template.FeatureWrapper" class on Geoserver looks like bbox is not available (You could check it too to see all available variables parsed). But still you can get the Geometry WKT which is useful for to recreate bbox:

content.ftl:

```
<ul>

<#list features as feature>
  <li><b>Type: ${type.name}</b> (id: <em>${feature.fid}</em>):

  <ul>
  <#list feature.attributes as attribute>

    <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
      <li>${attribute.name}: ${attribute.value}</li>
    </#if>
    <#if attribute.isGeometry>
      <li>geometry: ${attribute.value}</li>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  </ul>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>
```

Now if you use another response format like "info_format=application/json" on your HTTP query you will get BBOX and another useful information:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "totalFeatures":"unknown",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":"5095",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  -17.4229,
                  36.4734
               ],
               [
                  -17.4229,
                  36.4734
               ]
            ]
         },
         "geometry_name":"geom",
         "properties":{
            "revision":53923202431,
            "name":"ASDF",
            "bbox":[
               -17.4229,
               36.4734,
               -17.4229,
               36.4734
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
      }
   },
   "bbox":[
      -17.4229,
      36.4734,
      -17.4229,
      36.4734
   ]
}
```

See https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo for more output formats.